# How to upload checkpoint to Kaggle?

Tags: kaggle

I'm trying to upload a PyTorch checkpoint to a Kaggle dataset, but it just says "Uploaded 0 of 1 file" with no progress. See screenshot. What am I doing wrong?
[image: Upload dialog]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to zip it and upload a .zip file, even though the ckpt file is basically zipped already.